# Model binding to Dictionary from URI in ASP.NET Web API

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Please refer to this link from MVC: http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/discussions/351011

I am having trouble with model binding. From JavaScript I do an GET Ajax request to my API end point called "/api/products" passing in some parameters including paging and sorting as query parameters. Here is the complete URI:

```
http://localhost/api/products?page=1&count=10&filter[name]=Test1&filter[price]=10&sorting[name]=desc
```

On the server side, I have an Web API controller accepting these properties from the URI:

```
public async IHttpActionResult Get([FromUri]Dictionary<string,string> filter, [FromUri]Dictionary<string,string> sorting, int count, int page)
{
        //...
}
```

The "count" and "page" parameters bind perfectly fine, and the filter and sorting binds as an instance of a dictionary, but its count is 0.

I got this working in MVC but it doesn't seem to be doing the truck in Web API.

Comment: Check the solution proposed at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11950351/method-with-dictionary-parameter-in-asp-net-web-api

Answer (score 4):

You can still leverage out of the box default model binder and your uri would look like

```
http://localhost/api/products?page=1&count=10&filter[0].key=name&filter[0].value=Test1&filter[1].key=price&filter[0].value=10&sorting[0].key=name&sorting[0].value=desc
```

Comment: @LawrenceAiello, it's clearly apparent that the above link isn't a link to an off-site resource, but rather an example of a URL format.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to use a model as parameter, such as:

```
Public class model
{
Public Dictionary<string,string> filter{get;set;}
Public Dictionary<string,string> sorting{get;set;}
Public int sorting{get;set;}
}

public async IHttpActionResult Get(model yourModel)
{
        //...
}
```

Comment: Hi Shahrooz, I've tried that but it's still not binding correctly on the dictionary properties

Comment: @FanieReynders Please read:http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx

Comment: As I understand, modelbinding in web api works different from mvc

Comment: @FanieReynders Yes very different

Answer (score 0):

You could use a JSON string to keep the url short. The URI would be like

http://localhost/api/products?filter={"name":"Test","price":10}

Web API controller:

```cs
public void Get(string filter)
{
    var filterDictionary = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(filter);
    //...
}
```